# Text edit issue with replace method

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a text file , edit some of its content and write it in another text file.While editing I'm looking for certain keywords.These keywords, if present have to be replaced by new ones.The code is reading and writing properly but the keywords are not getting replaced.I have no idea why.Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/lenov/workspace/TemplateAutomation/src/input/testinput.txt"));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/lenov/workspace/TemplateAutomation/src/output/testoutput.txt", "UTF-8");
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contentEquals("CONTRACTNUMBER")) {
            line.replace("CONTRACTNUMBER", "NEW");
        }
        System.out.println("System.out.println(\"" + line + "\");");
        writer.println("System.out.println(\"" + line + "\");");
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: FORMAT YOUR CODE. First use an IDE to indent your code then use the `{}` button on the editor to format as code. This is illegible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line.replace("CONTRACTNUMBER","NEW");
```

won't do anything, as `replace()` doesn't change the String (it can't, because strings in Java are immutable). It creates and returns a new one and returns it. You are probably looking for

```
line = line.replace("CONTRACTNUMBER","NEW");
```

If your line equals `"CONTRACTNUMBER"` and you want it to be `"NEW"`, you can simply write `line = "NEW";`, otherwise, if you want to replace every `"CONTRACTNUMBER"` in your current line, you should probably use the `contains()` method in your `if` condition.

---

Also, if you're dealing with Strings, you can use `.equals()` instead of `.contentEquals()`.